# how to keep the session alive for 3min using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

we are working on performance testing using JMeter, Can any one please provide information how to keep the Session alive using jmeter for 3 minuts or more.

Answer (score 0):

To keep session alive , you need to check option **"Use KeepAlive"** in your http sampler.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add a HTTP Cookie Manager at the Thread Group level, so as to ensure that all HTTP requests will share the same cookies.

Right click your Thread Group, and then add Config Element -> HTTP Cookie Manager.

More details about HTTP Cookie Manager: http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html